# How to set margin in inflated linearlayout dynamically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have added a `linearlayout` in a `linearlayout` dynamically using this code.

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
root.addView(child , index++);
```

I want to add bottom margin in childview. Can I do this dynamically?

Comment: [Refer to this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5715715/854864) You can use `setLayoutParams`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin,rightMargin, bottomMargin);
child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
root.addView(child , index++);
```

Comment: getting null pointer exception in this line params.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin,rightMargin, bottomMargin);

Comment: I haven't tested the code . This is how we do it. Any how what does logcat say here ???

Comment: @rAviNder It probably says "NullPointerException".  Sorry, I had to.

Comment: Posting wrong, not tested code makes no point, sorry. Instead of: //LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();   Add:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Answer (score 2):

```
LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);
child.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The **params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);** allows to set margins for left, top, right and bottom respectively. So to set a margin to the bottom of your child view, replace 5 with a number of your choice.

Hope this will help.. :)

Comment: I can't set this line params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);

Comment: It says add cast to params.

Comment: yes you have to cast it like LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

Comment: the problem is in this line params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);

Comment: I got it.. Hope the variable declaration is wrong. That's why you are getting the error. I think if you cast it using "(LayoutParams)" in the declaration statement, the error will be rectified.